# Unable to download java or uninstall it (version 14.02) on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg, java, dependencies

Please help me!! I am stuck for the past 3 days and being unable to install java on my ubuntu 18.04; nothing is working out :-(; as I have very little information though I tried like oracle.com>java14 installer kit>downloaded tar.gz file>unable to set it.
Below are detailed query:

Neither apt --fix-broken install not working and nor sudo apt autoremove and dpkg is saying not installed but on installing it says dpkg is already on updated version::

```
adrino@Inspiron:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for adrino: 
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease            
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease              
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed InRelease            
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:8 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease                
Reading package lists... Done

adrino@Inspiron:~$ sudo apt-get upgradable
E: Invalid operation upgradable
adrino@Inspiron:~$ sudo apt list upgradable
Listing... Done

adrino@Inspiron:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: openjdk-11-jdk
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-11-jre
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

adrino@Inspiron:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386
  libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libatomic1:i386
  libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
  libblkid1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcap2:i386 libcapi20-3:i386
  libcdparanoia0:i386 libcom-err2:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcups2:i386
  libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386
  libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libgd3:i386
  libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libglib2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libglx0:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386 libgpg-error0:i386
  libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgpm2:i386 libgsm1:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
  libhogweed4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libicu60:i386 libidn2-0:i386
  libieee1284-3:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386
  libllvm10:i386 libltdl7:i386 liblz4-1:i386 libmount1:i386 libmpg123-0:i386
  libncurses5:i386 libnettle6:i386 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpcap0.8:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libpng16-16:i386
  libpulse0:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsane1:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libsensors4:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio6.1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.1:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libsystemd0:i386
  libtasn1-6:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtinfo5:i386 libudev1:i386
  libunistring2:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386
  libwebp6:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
  libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386
  libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386
  libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386
  libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzstd1:i386
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 wine32:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java14-installer oracle-java14-set-default
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk | ttf-unfonts | ttf-unfonts-core
  ttf-kochi-gothic | ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho
  | ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gsfonts-x11 oracle-java14-set-default
The following packages will be upgraded:
  oracle-java14-installer
1 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/43.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 237 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y      
Preconfiguring packages ...
/tmp/oracle-java14-installer.config.E2htyx: 18: /tmp/oracle-java14-installer.config.E2htyx: dpkg: not found
oracle-java14-installer failed to preconfigure, with exit status 20
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)

adrino@Inspiron:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: openjdk-11-jdk
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-11-jre
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

adrino@Inspiron:~$
```

Comment: you can install openjdk-14-jdk using the command sudo apt install openjdk-14-jdk which is almost the same as jdk from oracle

Comment: @kannzzmm2 this command would work great in 20.04 and later, but the author is using 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? I see errors on Java 11 packages and errors on Java 14 packages. Which version do you want to install? In any case: my suggestion would be to completely remove all Java packages and then try to install the version you want.

I see two problems, one with `oracle-java14-installer` and one with `openjdk-11-jre`. You say you tried to install Java by downloading the .tar.gz file from Oracle, but the problems you are having appear not to be related.

The first problem is with `oracle-java14-installer`. This seems to come from the package `oracle-java14-installer_14.0.2-1~linuxuprising1` from PPA http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu. This is a PPA you've added yourself. Try to delete the package using `sudo apt-get --purge remove oracle-java14-*`.

The output of `sudo apt autoremove` says `The following packages have unmet dependencies: default-jdk : Depends: openjdk-11-jdk default-jre : Depends: openjdk-11-jre`. This looks to me like package `openjdk-11-jre` is missing. What happens when you install that? Do a `sudo apt update` first, and then a `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre`. Is the output of `sudo apt autoremove` without errors now?

Comment: on running command sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre following is what I am receiving::

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: openjdk-11-jdk
 openjdk-11-jre : Depends: libgif7 (>= 5.1) but it is not going to be installed
 Recommends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: fonts-dejavu-extra but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: result of sudo apt autoremove is  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 default-jdk : Depends: openjdk-11-jdk
 default-jre : Depends: openjdk-11-jre
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve? The output of `sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre` lists another package that is missing. Try to find that one yourself as an exercise! By combining your original question, my post, and your comment.